# Требуется кэшировать данные приходящие в json формате

Tags: java, android, json, android-sqlite

Ситуация такая, что делается запрос, ответ в json, его надо сохранить, чтобы в след раз при таком же запросе брать данные из кэша. Хотя json легкий, поэтому в кэш стоит лезть в случае отсутствия интернета.

Какие средства для этого подойдут лучше в всего? Sql? Просто читаю такие ответы как: sql на смартфоне - извращение (правда 2013 года ) Так как проще  хранить в словаре, если объем не более 50 мб. Еще говорят, что json хранить не умно. Почему? Распарсить json по полям класса и сохранять экземпляры классов что ли? Для андроид используют sqlLite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Хотя json легкий, поэтому в кэш стоит лезть в случае отсутствия интернета.

В кэш стоит лезть в любом случае. Чтение локальных данных происходит быстрее, чем чтение данных, расположенных удаленно.

> Какие средства для этого подойдут лучше в всего?

Это зависит от данных, которые требуется хранить. Например, можно использовать базу данных. Если Вы ранее не работали с БД, то для начала можно попробовать [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html). После знакомства с SQLite, можно попробовать какую-нибудь ORM (greenDAO, Sugar ORM, DBFlow и прочие). После этого можно попробовать Realm.

Чистый SQL работает быстрее, чем ORM. Realm, [говорят](https://realm.io/products/realm-database), в некоторых случаях работает быстрее чистого SQL.

Также можно попробовать [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html), про который Google пишет:

> we highly recommend using Room instead of SQLite.

---

> Просто читаю такие ответы как: sql на смартфоне - извращение (правда 2013 года )

Это бред.

> Еще говорят, что json хранить не умно. Почему? Распарсить json по полям класса и сохранять экземпляры классов что ли?

Если Вам нужно хранить несколько json (например, 5-10, **без дальнейшего масштабирования**), то их можно хранить банально в файле. Если же в приложении будут хранится много данных и приложением будем ими манипулировать, то целесообразно использовать базу данных.

Comment: Я понял, всё очень полезно. Но все же почему я не могу хранить json в базе данных? Немного поясню. В полученном json данные для всего UI, по отдельности эти данные не используются. Самих json может быть много, на сервере на каждый день с 2000 годов по 100 видов json.  Я кэширую лишь часть. Не проще ли хранить в базе данных json , имя - ключ, а текст в другом столбце. Единственное где я проигрываю это в том, что когда json приходит изначально, я его парсю и теперь когда обращусь к БД, мне его снова придется парсить. Это ли основной минус или есть еще какой нибудь?

Comment: @Turalllb, Один из минусов -- отсутствие гибкости: Вы не сможете фильтровать выборку из БД. Ну про парсинг тоже, да. Также будет проблематично использовать ORM.

Comment: Какая мне может понадобиться выборка? один json = один UI. Т.е. мне не понадобится из этого json достать например только адреса. Поэтому в этом случае выборка незачем. Вам тяжело отвечать не зная конкретной задачи, может и ORM в пределах этой задачи отлично сработает. Не суть. Моя цель изучить, а не выполнить задачу.

Comment: Но у меня остался один вопрос: Если есть таблица из одного столбца и в нём каждое название уникально "ГОД_ДЕНЬ"  и таких строк в таблице с 2000 года  много, ускорит ли работу если я разделю на базы из разных, например, годов.  Мне хочется узнать, поиск по таблице является ли банальным сканированием по всем данным?  Или же еще лучше: одна таблица, но каждый столбец хранит один год. Т.е. СУБД не надо проходиться по всем столбцам. И это будет достаточной выборкой. Выборка из отдельных элементов, что хранит json, мне не нужна, а вот из самих данных снимет нагрузку.

Comment: Не правильно выразился. Одна база данных, но в ней четыре таблицы. Одна хранит года, другой месяца,  третья - дни и четвертая сам json. Каждая строка получается уникальна, за счет уникальности года. База реляционная. Можно работать.

Comment: Согласитесь, в таком случае , мне выборка из внутренностей одного json ответа не нужна.

Comment: С тем , что база получилась реляционная я погорячился) она не  нормализованная , но это не тяжело исправить.

Comment: Не нужно хранить компоненты даты отдельно. Можно завести атрибут типа Date.

Comment: Хм..спасибо, я просто еще пробовал SQLite, не знал что там такой вариант есть.

Answer (score 2):

Голову не грейте возьмите [DiskLRUCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache)

Таки лучше взять с [врэппером](https://github.com/fhucho/simple-disk-cache) который намного упростит работу с кэшем:

```
//инициализация кэша
SimpleDiskCache cache=new SimpleDiskCache.open(dir, appVersion, capacityBytes);


//положить в кэш строку
cache.put(key, jsonString); 
//blah-blah
jsonString=cache.get(key); //взять из кэша строку
if(jsonString==null)
    //читаем из сети
```

Минус в том, что каждая запись - это файл на диске, плюс - не надо голову особо греть.

Comment: Спасибо, это тоже пригодится, когда не будет времени париться с созданием базы и с  изучением всего остального. Но я как раз изучаю и хочу чтобы в резюме появился пункт Опыт работы с sqLite.